# Change container div class acording to lang file being used

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a div with a background image and I need it to change the class of that div depending on the language (I'm using laravel blade) selected.
For example: when english is selected my class is bg-en and when spanish is selected, it is bg-sp.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: How do you select the language? Where do you keep this value? Can you show us any of your code?

Comment: can you show us some code or a ready-to-use [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/). Would be much easier to help then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set your language using `App::setLocale($lang)`, you can use in Blade:

```
<div class="bg-{{{ App::getLocale() }}}">
rest of code here
</div>
```